# How to add attribute to a list to access y coordinate

Tags: python, pygame

I have a function which creates rectangle . With a for loop ,I create few rectangles and store them in a rectangles named list.
These are the enemy rectangles

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self ,color ,x,y,w,h):
        self.c = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.rect =pygame.Rect(self.x ,self.y ,self.w ,self.h)
    
    def update(self ,rectangles):
        self.rect.y += sy
        
        rectlist =[r.rect for r in rectangles if r != self]
        if self.rect.y > height:
            self.rect.y = -25
            self.rect.x = random.randint(10,900)
            while self.rect.collidelist(rectlist) > -1:
                
                self.rect.x = random.randint(10,900)
    
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(display , self.c ,self.rect)
        
    

for count in range(6):
    r_c = random.randint(0,255) , random.randint(0,255) , random.randint(0,255) 
    create_new = True
    while create_new:
     
        r_x = random.randint(10,900)
        r_y = random.randint(0,10)
        r_w = random.randint(60,100) 
        r_h = random.randint(40,80) 
    
    
        rectangle = Rectangle(r_c ,r_x,r_y,r_w,r_h)
        create_new = rectangle.rect.collidelist(rectlist) > -1
        
    rectangles.append(rectangle)
    rectlist.append(rectangle.rect)

pc=p.collidelistall(rectangles)
k = len(pc)
```

`p` is the name of our player.
I want to know with which rectangle it has collided ,because I want to find the difference between the player y coordinate and enemy y coordinate.

```py
ob = [rectangles[i] for i in pc]
```

I store that rectangles that collided in a on list.
I want to access y coordinate of those rectangles ,and do some operations on it ,but the list ob don't have the attribute needed to access y coordinate.
What should I do to access y coordinate.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ob` is a list of `Rectangle` objects. A `Rectangle` object has the `rect`. `rect` is a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelistall) object.

You can get a rectangle from the list by [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-subscription). For instance get the `y` coordinate of the 1st rectangle in the list:

```py
y = ob[0].rect.y
```

Or access all the elements in a loop:

```py
for r in ob:
    y = r.rect.y
```